# Why is pip installed in virtual environments by default?

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

Python's `venv` module is installing `pip` in created virtual environments by default, unless instructed not to using `--without-pip`, as described in [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments). Why is that so?

If `pip` is "just" a package manager, I don't see why it should in any way be coupled to the used Python interpreter or installed packages. I wonder why the system's pip is not used instead to manage all environments. Indeed, pip's documentation ([pip.pypa.io](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/python-option/)) only describes how this can be done and does not discourage it.

```bash
$ python -m venv .venv --without-pip
$ python -m pip --python .venv install SomePackage
```

Comment: How else do you want to install packages in a virtual environment?

Comment: One obvious way would be with the snippet in the question. That's not exactly handy, but It should also be possible to create an alias in the virtual environment which simply points to the system's pip. Therefore, I assume there should be further (technical) reasons for this.

Comment: You should find the PEP proposing this, read it and read the discussions in the Python community about it. Then you might understand why it was done like that.

Comment: `python -m pip` requires `pip` (the library). If `pip` (the script) is installed doesn't matter that much, it's just a 8 line script that imports `pip` (the library) and calls its `main()` function. The bottom line: `pip` (the library) must be installed. The end of the story.

Comment: If I create the .venv environment as in the question with Python 3.8, I would also get `.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip`. As I understand, **this** is what the 8 line script imports, and it sure isn't my system's pip. Why?

Comment: That's not specific to `pip`. Python virtual environments is a tool to separate different versions of Python libraries. Everything installed into a venv is separated from the global set of libraries and and from any other venv. That's how and why venvs work. `pip` is just one example of such separation.

Comment: I agree that `pip` is just another component that can be separated from the rest of the system, but my question is why would that be necessary. `pip` is never listed as dependency when using `pip freeze` and hardly any projects really rely on a specific version of it. You don't see NPM, Maven and co being installed separately for every project that uses them. 

I will try to find the PEP later and post anything interesting I found here.

Comment: Global `pip` installs Python libraries into the global `site-packages`. `pip` from a venv installs Python libraries into the venv's `site-packages`. There is no way to tell global `pip` to install Python libraries into the venv's `site-packages` (and vice versa). Very much unlike `npm` that has `-g/--global` flag (I know nothing about Maven, perhaps it has a similar flag?)

Comment: There sure is, you can use `python -m pip --python .venv install some-package`. This would install `some-package` in `.venv`. Now I saw this wasn't possible in pip 20.0.2, but is with 23.2.1, I don't know when the feature was added.

Comment: Wow so much negativity here... As a Python venv user, I get a venv where `python` is a linked system Python, `os` is linked system Python's `os; why would `pip` not follow the same pattern? Why does `pip` deserve to be copied into venv, and not only that, in my experience it's often different version than system `pip`...

Comment: From my experience, rarely an arbitrary decision is taken in the Python community. And frankly, the first comment is ignorant at best, there are indeed other ways. The snippet in my question is not pseudo code! Having seen other approaches, I was curious why ‘venv’ decided to go that way and naively tried to ask on SO. Sorry, can’t offer any ‘NullPointerException’s for you to catch today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the reasoning/justification as given in [PEP-453](https://peps.python.org/pep-0453/):

> Python 3.3 included a standard library approach to virtual Python
> environments through the venv module. Since its release it has become
> clear that very few users have been willing to use this feature
> directly, in part due to the lack of an installer present by default
> inside of the virtual environment. They have instead opted to continue
> using the virtualenv package which does include pip installed by
> default.
>
> To make the venv more useful to users it will be modified to issue the
> pip bootstrap by default inside of the new environment while creating
> it. This will allow people the same convenience inside of the virtual
> environment as this PEP provides outside of it as well as bringing the
> venv module closer to feature parity with the external virtualenv
> package, making it a more suitable replacement.
>
> To handle cases where a user does not wish to have pip bootstrapped
> into their virtual environment a --without-pip option will be added.
>
> The venv.EnvBuilder and venv.create APIs will be updated to accept one
> new parameter: with_pip (defaulting to False).
>
> The new default for the module API is chosen for backwards
> compatibility with the current behaviour (as it is assumed that most
> invocation of the venv module happens through third part tools that
> likely will not want pip installed without explicitly requesting it),
> while the default for the command line interface is chosen to try to
> ensure pip is available in most virtual environments without
> additional action on the part of the end user.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering just out of curiosity, but that last paragraph might actually explain some weird issues I was having recently.

Answer (score 2):

The [`--python`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#cmdoption-python) argument you've mentioned, which allows pip to manage some environment *other* than the one it is installed in, is really new. It's from [PR #11320](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11320) which arrived in
pip 22.3 ([Oct 2022](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v22-3)), that's less than a year since this question was asked.

In contrast, the stdlib `venv` module arrived way back in Python 3.3, released more than a decade ago. So, until pretty recently, the normal way to install/remove packages in a venv was to have a pip installation (and a setuptools installation) in the venv and that's why it's installed by default.

If you don't want pip installed into your venvs, and prefer to manage the packages in them from an external `pip >= 22.3`, then by all means use the `--without-pip` option when creating your venv.

I've been managing venvs externally with some other pip installation for a while and it works well, I haven't found any issues. The environment with the pip installation doesn't even need to be the same Python version as the target environment, [environment markers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers) and [Requires-Python](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python) metadata are handled correctly, respecting the target runtime. One point to note is that the target environment does still need to be *supported* by the running pip version, so you can't manage an old Python < 3.7 env like this, because the earliest version of pip with the `--python` feature requires Python >= 3.7.